# Swapping isEnabled of UITextField changes background color and how to prevent it

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, uitextfield

I have two `UITextField`s with one `isEnabled` set false. When I swap `isEnabled` of the two text fields, one become enabled after swap changes background color to light gray automatically.

I'm guessing it is some feature UIKit provides automatically but I want it to be disabled.

```
    func swapEvaluatedMoreAndLess() {
        
        // - Prepare Values
        
        // Use shortened name ref since originals are named bit long
        let moreField: UITextField = placeEvaluatedMoreTextField
        let lessField: UITextField = placeEvaluatedLessTextField
        
        // Store ref
        let moreText: String? = moreField.text
        let lessText: String? = lessField.text
        
        let moreFieldEnabled: Bool = moreField.isEnabled
        let lessFieldEnabled: Bool = lessField.isEnabled
        
        
        
        // - Swap
        
        // Swap text
        placeEvaluatedMoreTextField.text = lessText
        placeEvaluatedLessTextField.text = moreText
        
        // Swap isEnabled
        placeEvaluatedMoreTextField.isEnabled = lessFieldEnabled
        placeEvaluatedLessTextField.isEnabled = moreFieldEnabled
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try `isUserInteractionEnabled`, this property won't change the background color and stop receiving users' touch events.